# text box insertion after selection of country

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have a form , where users has to select a country from the following.if users select Australia i want to populate one more text field where users can enter there mobile number so that for that particular country i can store mobile number of those users.i tried with if statement but its not working . 
during the signup process if users select Australia i want them to enter there mobile number also and for other users mobile number is not required

```
if(location==Australia){
echo'<tr>
<td width="49" ><div align="left"></p><p>
Mobile No</div></td><td>
<input type="text" size="20" name="mobile" value="'.h($_REQUEST['mobile']).'"  class="fpost" style="width:220px" /></tr>';}



<tr class="row1"><td>Come from</td><td>
                <select name="location" class="inputText"><option value="Afghanistan  ">Afghanistan  </option><option value="Albania  ">Albania  </option><option value="Algeria  ">Algeria  </option><option value="American Samoa  ">American Samoa  </option><option value="Andorra  ">Andorra  </option><option value="Angola  ">Angola  </option><option value="Anguilla  ">Anguilla  </option><option value="Antarctica  ">Antarctica  </option><option value="Ant &amp; Bar  ">Ant &amp; Bar  </option><option value="Argentina  ">Argentina  </option><option value="Armenia  ">Armenia  </option><option value="Aruba  ">Aruba  </option><option value="Australia  ">Australia  </option><option value="Austria  ">Austria  </option><option value="Azerbaijan  ">Azerbaijan  </option><option value="Bahamas  ">Bahamas  </option><option value="Bahrain  ">Bahrain  </option><option value="Bangladesh  ">Bangladesh  </option><option value="Barbados  ">Barbados  </option><option value="Belarus  ">Belarus  </option><option value="Belgium  ">Belgium  </option><option value="Belize  ">Belize  </option><option value="Benin  ">Benin  </option><option value="Bermuda  ">Bermuda  </option><option value="Bhutan  ">Bhutan  </option><option value="Bolivia  ">Bolivia  </option><option value="Bosnia ">Bosnia </option><option value="Botswana  ">Botswana  </option><option value="Bouvet">Bouvet</option><option value="Brazil  ">Brazil  </option><option value="Brunei">Brunei</option><option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option></select>
```

Comment: where is your "if statement" that is not working? i just see static html code.

Comment: Please remove all these countries in the options list, two or three will be sufficient as a sample

Comment: mother of god, imagine adding a new country, don't repeat yourself if you don't have to

Comment: PHP is executed on the server side. you can not dynamically access DOM elements with PHP. Try using javascript, query and @Rajat Singhal's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try and separate my output logic from my data with something like this, where `$countries` is an array of strings of country names.

```
<tr class="row1">
    <td>Come from</td>
    <td>
    <select name="location" id="location" class="inputText">
<?php
    foreach ($counties as $country) {
        echo '<option value="', $country, '">', $country, '</option>';
    }
?>
    </select>
    <td>
</tr>
```

Then, I would use the `.change()` function of jQuery or a similar framework to handle the dropdown.

```
$('#location').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Australia') {
        // Show the text box
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess you want something like this... (Pure javascript. Without jQuery. For the following code to work, add an ID to the `select` element and another for the `textbox` element)

```
var showTextBox = function(prefix) { // Function to add the textbox with defined value
    var textBox = document.getElementById('textbox')
    textBox.value = prefix
    textBox.style.display = 'block'
}
document.getElementById('select').onchange = function(e) {
    var target = e.target || window.event // Cross-browser target
    switch (target.value) { // Depending on the value
        case 'Australia':
            showTextBox('+61 ') // Use the function with the correct prefix
            break;
        case 'otherCountry':
            showTextBox('+XX ')
    }
}
```

The `switch` statement makes it so that if you later want to add another country, it is easy to do so.

P.S: [I'm feeling lonely](https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/img/9684882892c9c6beb3d05fce03b12a4eb37f7518/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f73735255722e676966).

Answer (score 1):

If you include the [jQuery Library](http://www.jquery.com/) on your page, you can achive this, including a nice slide effect.

Add `id="mobile_container"` to the `tr` element that contains the mobile number field, and add something like this to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    // Hide the mobile field initially
    if($("select[name='location']").val() != 'Australia') {
        $("tr#mobile_container").hide();
    }

    $("select[name='location']").change(function(){
        // This fires when user changes location
        if($(this).val() == 'Australia') {
            // Australia selected, let's show the mobile row
            $("tr#mobile_container").slideDown();
        } else {
            // Australia not selected, we make sure mobile row is hidden
            $("tr#mobile_container").slideUp();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: tried but not working here is my code   <script type="text/javascript">$(function() {
    if($("select[name=\'location\']").val() != \'Australia\') {
        $("tr#mobile").hide();
    }

    $("select[name=\'location\']").change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == \'Australia\') {
            $("tr#mobile").slideDown();
        } else {
            $("tr#mobile").slideUp();
        }
    });
});</script><tr id="mobile"><td width="49" ><div align="left"></p><p>Mobile No</div></td><td><input  type="text" size="20" name="mobno" value="'.h($_REQUEST['mobno']).'" /></tr>';

Comment: Add a `</td>` before your `</tr>`. And also make sure that the tr is indeed a part of a `<table>`. You should also remove the trailing whitespaces in your option values (e.g. `value="Australia"`, not `value="Australia  "`). Also note that the jQuery slide functions does nok look very pretty on table rows. I suggest a table-less layout, alternatively can use show() instead of slideDown() and hide() instead of slideUp(). I second the other commenters regarding how you output the country list; your code will not be easy to maintain; consider a nice PHP array and loop instead.

Comment: i love that you actually hide the input for the mobile number with javascript, and not php. this way people can submit this form even if they have javascript disabled. +1

Comment: @user1096307 you changed elaxsj's example code. for instance you wrote `if($(this).val() == \'Australia\')` instead of `if($(this).val() == 'Australia')`. you added backslashes to the statement, so that it won't work. you should also get a syntax error reported by your browser. elaxsj's example will work perfectly, if you just integrate it correctly.